What can be the datatype of these two parameters
I recently got this simple C++ programming code. I tried to find the data types of those two parameters. But I can't. is anyone know what data type want to be used here?
This is the code. I tried double but there is also a string as parameter
#include <iostream>
    
using namespace std;
    
void func(double val1 ,double val2) {

    cout << val1 << " " << val2 << endl;
}
    
int main(){

    func(8, 10);
    func(33, "Hi there");
    func(2.5, 16.5);
    return 0;
}


That code won't compile.

https://ideone.com/BXKHVe shows the very detailed compiler error for the string literal. Comment out func(33, "Hi there");   and it should compile.

To make all those func calls in the main work you need either function overloading or templates, but those may be too advanced topics for you now. You may look up these keywords if you are interested.

Write two functions, one with double, double and the other with double, string. Then (and this is the clue) give both those functions the same name. This is called function overloading.

The code will not compile with any single instance of func because there is no type that can be used to pass both numeric values and strings in a trivial way.
Since you tagged with C++, one solution would be to use a function template.
The types for the paramaters would be templated and so the compiler will instantiate as many instances of func as needed in order to be used with the argumnents you supply.
It would work because std::cout already has operator<< overloads for all the types you currently use:
#include <iostream>

template <typename T1, typename T2>
void func(T1 const & val1, T2 const & val2) {
    std::cout << val1 << " " << val2 << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    func(8, 10);
    func(33, "Hi there");
    func(2.5, 16.5);
}

Output:
8 10
33 Hi there
2.5 16.5

Live demo
A side note: it's better to avoid using namespace std; - see here: using namespace std.

C++ is a strongly typed language. Hence function parameters expects typed arguments.
When you define a function like this
void func(double val1 ,double val2){

cout << val1 << " " << val2 << endl;}

C++ compiler expects first parameter to be double or any type that can be converted to a double (int, unsigned int etc)
Similarly compiler expects second parameter to be double on any other type that can be convertible to double.
Now coming to your first function call.
Although type is passed as int , compiler does not complain because int can be converted to double.
func(8, 10); // first function call
func(33, "Hi there"); // second function call
Now coming to the second function call
Here compiler does not know how to convert the second arguement("Hi there")type which is a character array to double.
Hence this results in compiler error.
To fix this issue you can define an overloaded function for func which expects its second parameter as std::string like below
void func(double val1, std::string val2){}

Complete code  is provided for your reference
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
void func(double val1, double val2) {
    cout << val1 << " " << val2 << endl;
}
void func(double val1, std::string val2) {
    cout << val1 << " " << val2 << endl;
}
int main() {
    func(8, 10);
    func(12, std::string("Hi there"));
    func(2.5, 16.5);
    return 0;
}


std::string in func(12, std::string("Hi there")) is redundant, func(12, "Hi there") is enough. The function signature of your second overload is unconventional. const std::string& or std::string_view or const char* should be used for the second pararmeter instead to avoid unnecessary copy in the general case. Also please avoid using namespace std;.

In the call func(8, 10); both arguments would be converted to doubles which might be undesired. Same goes for some other arguments. IMHO a function template as shown in my answer is a better solution here.

Hi @wohlstad, I agree. const std::string& std::string_view or const char* is better. I just want to suggest about how he can get the desired output.
Also template is the best solution, but those who are not comfortable with template I have provided an alternate solution.
